# IQ-EQ oscillation

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, intelligence, iq, emotional-intelligence

I know a guy who was very smart in school and university and had a high IQ. For example, in middle school he used to read high school science and math books like they're nothing but he had low EQ and low emotion control (probably because he had no father figure). Now this guy is in his late 30s and he say he's not as smart as he was, he has trouble understanding some of what he wrote or read 15 years ago, but he now understand emotions better which is clear when you see him interact with other people.

He used to analyze people logically which led him to many awkward moments and many confrontations (especially with girls) when he explained the inconsistencies in their arguments but now he really can read people emotions from their body language, their voice, their words.... which led him to wonder if some of his IQ became EQ. Suppose that he decides to live far from people and study his favorite subjects again, will his EQ decrease and become IQ?

Comment: Questions about individuals are off-topic here.  Please rephrase the question to apply more generally, otherwise it should be closed.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg This guy is just an example. I'm not asking to study his case, I'm asking if it's possible that some of the IQ becomes EQ? Has this phenomenon been studied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IQ" is a very broad and full of misconceptions. While it may be the most popular form for measuring intelligence, it has been debated a lot of it's scientific properties and accuracy.

In the case you explain,the individual in question has high understanding of mathematics and logic and low emotional intelligence. If we are following the famous interpretation of [Gardner's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Gardner) of intelligence with the [Theory of Multiple intelligences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_multiple_intelligences), **there is no direct correlation between the two**; but, by logic and human limitations, not everyone can have high intelligence in all its different encarnations. It can be perfectly normal to be considered a genius in some area but "average" in others.

As we understand this, it is no secret that an emotional unstable person may have difficulties getting their thoughts in order and may have poor performance by stressful factors formed by their disruptive psyche. I feel obligated to note that to be unstable by your emotions, you need to first recognize and acknowledge them, and to do that you need to develop some tools provided by emotional intelligence.

And as well, there are many theories that as we grow old if not maintained and reinforced, our intelligence may start to [deteriorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_of_intelligence), and that many factors that increase this process are tied to psychological stress.

There is definitely endless variables that can not be determined by the lack of details in the case proposed, but this is just a broad interpretation and should not be taken as absolute truth and be used to explain every person that may fit this case.

If you want to research more on your own, the previously mentioned Garner's [Multiple Intelligences: New Horizons in Theory and Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465047688) is a must read to understand one of the most prominent theories of intelligence.

Emotional intelligence can be studied in much more detail in the work of [Goleman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Goleman) in Emotional Intelligence.

And while it can be a heavy read, any serious book on neuroplascity can be helpful to understand the ever changing brain and it's functions and "agility". For example, [Neuroplasticity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262529335) by Mohed Constandi.

Hope this answer helps you.